# Can I disable entities resolving in ElementTree XMLParser?

Tags: python, lxml, elementtree, xml.etree

With lxml I can:

```
from lxml import etree
parser = etree.XMLParser(resolve_entities=False)
```

Can I do the same with xml.etree.ElementTree XMLParser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick look at the source code shows nothing as easy as `resolve_entities=False`.

Here is an extract of [the source of xml.etree.ElementTree.XMLParser](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/xml/etree/ElementTree.py#l1443):

```
parser.DefaultHandlerExpand = self._default
parser.StartElementHandler = self._start
parser.EndElementHandler = self._end
parser.CharacterDataHandler = self._data
# optional callbacks
parser.CommentHandler = self._comment
parser.ProcessingInstructionHandler = self._pi
```

There are no other pyexpat handlers configured.

Now, are you interested in well-known XML entities like `&amp;` or others? It seems like undefined entities are going through `XMLParser._default` so you might get something by extending that method.

But what are you trying to accomplish with this? If this is only adding new entities, try updating the `XMLParser.entity` dict.

Comment: I wanted to avoid using `parser = ElementTree.XMLParser(); parser.parser.UseForeignDTD(True); parser.entity['nbsp'] = '&#x00A0;'` and similar possibilities in potential XHTML files I feed the script with

Comment: Oh, so you already had a solution :/
Then no, I’m afraid there is nothing simpler than that.